# template_redirect not being called when using ajax

Tags: plugins, plugin-development, hooks, actions

Usually I hook all my custom plugins code with the `template_redirect` hook but one of the issue I encountered is it does not work for the ajax call.

So if I want to target both standard calls and ajax call what hook should I use?

Is `wp_loaded` a good choice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For AJAX you need to hook into the [wp_ajax_{action}](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/wp_ajax_%28action%29) hook

Specifically,

```
add_action('wp_ajax_my_action', 'my_action_callback');
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_my_action', 'my_action_callback');
```

See http://codex.wordpress.org/AJAX_in_Plugins

Comment: Sorry, maybe I asked the wrong question, I mean what hook should I use if I want both standard page request and ajax request will invoke my code.

Comment: sorry but I don't understand what you want to do

Comment: I want a way to hook so both normal and ajax request will be called. I am not sure if `wp_loaded` is the safest bet. (I assume template_redirect is the safest bet for normal page request but not for ajax)

Comment: if your question is whether `wp_loaded` is done every time wordpress is loaded including ajax, then the answer is yes